# SUITETALK- Netsuite searchAdvanced gives line price in base currency

Tags: netsuite

Can anyone please help us with this?

We are using Netsuite advanced search to pull sales order for different subsidiary. We are able to get all the line items(except tax itmes) but its consists the amount in base currency. Is there any way we can get response with exact amount visible in UI.

Also Its very hard to understand the basic of Netsuite SUITE TALk- SOAP. Do you recommend any resources that will ease learning?

Thanks

Comment: We are able to get the foreign line amount when adding `fxCost` on COLUMNS-> itemJOIN. We are still struggling to get the tax line for the subsidiary.

Comment: Can you please add an MCVE at your convenience?  (or at least a snippet that we can help with)?

Comment: Thanks @2ps for trying to help us, we are using our PHP tool kit for connecting Netsuite SOAP web service. And had own custom system to prepare arguments. So didn't have anything to share, Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Just an update with this question, with [Advanced search](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3659492.html) we are able to get the foreign currency of Subsidiary using fxCost in columns But line items doesn't have this option. This causes whole another problem for us. Then we decided to use [SAVED SEARCH](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/chapter_N675442.html). Saved search provides us feature to disable foregin currency just by choosing CONSOLIDATED EXCHANGE RATE to none. We are using saved search ID in the Advanced search paramater ie using savedSearchScriptId from Netsuite Schema.

Hope it would be helpful to anyone who is strugglign with this kind of issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For tax line in fx currency, prefer to do Tax Amount/exchange rate.

Comment: If you are adding SO via SUITE TALK, mostly we don't use Exchange rate which will caused exchange rate to remain on 1